# Can't get xml element text value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a an ajax call that returns an xml response. I want to get the value of one of the elements in this response , ie 'Some Name'. The problem is that there are 5 or 6 of these tags in the response. Is there a way to get the value of just the first one? It's always the first one I will want to use. 
Here is some of the code:

```
var xmlData = '<userId internalId="Some Number"xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformCore:name>Some Name</platformCore:name></userId>';
var $xml = $(xmlData);
var $user = $xml.find("platformCore:name").text();
alert($user);
```

I also have a js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8FqRd/5/

EDIT: FIX BELOW:

My ajax response was already in xml form, so no need to parse. This line worked for me:

```
var user = $(xmlResponse).find("userId").find("name").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main jQuery function doesn't parse XML correctly: it treats it as HTML, with variable results. Use [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead.

I'm not sure how jQuery deals with XML, particularly namespaces. I would guess not at all. However, searching for elements by local name rather than fully qualified name seems to work.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/8FqRd/6/

```
var xmlData = '<userId internalId="Some Number"xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformCore:name>Some Name</platformCore:name></userId>';
var $xml = $( $.parseXML(xmlData) );
var $user = $xml.find("name").text();
alert($user);
```

Comment: Will this work if I have multiple <platformCore:name> tags though?

Comment: @user2932418: [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the combined text of all the matched elements, so you could use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over them instead. I'd use raw DOM methods instead myself: `$.parseXML(xmlData).getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "name")`, for example.

Comment: Ok. This works in the jsfiddle you have provided, however, when i put this code into my javascript file in eclipse, it does not. Note: i'm creating an android application that uses html, js and css.

Comment: @user2932418: Not sure why that would be. It could be jQuery's selector engine. You could use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Might have to resort to using XPath instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim pointed out you need to use `$.parseXML(xmlData)`

However as your xml tag has a `:` in it, you will have to escape it.

```
var xmlData = '<userId internalId="Some Number" xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"><platformCore:name>Some Name</platformCore:name></userId>';
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlData);
var $xml = $(xml);
var $user = $xml.find("platformCore\\:name").text(); // you need to escape the : 
alert($user);
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/8FqRd/7/ for a demo

Comment: this does not work. There is nothing in the alert box in this fiddle.

Comment: Strange. I do get an alert

Comment: I was using chrome. Are you using a different browser? I've found the solution anyway. Thanks for your help